# can not display the image after convert

Tags: c#-4.0

i convert image to string that done successfully in SQL server. i do not know why image Not displayed in data grid view column? In general, what can be the reason why the image can not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Because that is unable  in datagrideview you can only display the path of the image or the binary data . You must use the namespace `Using System.IO`
and the extention `MemoryStream` to store it and show it again in special picture box